# Programming a maths image using matlab

Tags: matlab

i'm stuck on the function program (not the main) which have to plot a 3D figure showing several vertical sinusoidal curves.

Unfortunately, i got a plan instead of sinus curves. I don't know why it isn't working, i've been trying to find out what the problem during 2 hours...please help 
Thank you

```
%fonction sinus_vertical:
function img=sinus_vertical(N,M)
w=2*pi;
t=1:0.1:N;
for j=1:M
    for i=1:N
        for k=1:N
            img(i,j)=sin(w*t(k));
        end
    end
end
```

Main Program:

```
%Main Script
img3=sinus_vertical(100,100);
figure(1);
mesh(img3);
colormap gray
```

Comment: what do you mean by vertical sinusoidal curves? can you post an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you want, the simplest solution is this:

```
function img=sinus_vertical(N,M)
  w=2*pi;
  t=0.1*(1:N);
  img = repmat(sin(w*t)',1,M);
end
```

You can correct your original code, if you skip third inner loop, and modify setting up `t`.
So the correct code is:

```
function img=sinus_vertical(N,M)
    w=2*pi;
    t=0.1*(1:N);
    for j=1:M
        for i=1:N
            img(i,j)=sin(w*t(i)); % or j, depending on what direction you want the sin.
        end
    end
end
```

EXPLANATION:
I wrote you "don't need" the loop with the `k`, because if you do

```
for k=1:N
  img(i,j) = sin(w*t(k))
end
```

it is the same as writing `img(i,j)=sin(w*t(N))`. That is you would set all the image pixels to the same value.